# How to install Modules in Orchard CMS

Tags: module, slider, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm trying to use the FeaturedItemSlider Module in Orchard CMS, which has already been installed and enabled. How do I use this module after all this is done? I don't see it on the left hand navigation pane in the admin dashboard and, to be honest, I don't actually see any of my installed modules there. How do I use modules once they are installed?

Answer (score 0):

If you see no menu items for modules that you know should have items (and you should see one for that module called "Featured Items") then I would start by checking the log. There are a few scenarios that I have seen in the past where the module crashes out during enabling, but the module still says that it activated successfully.

Did you enable via command line or the Admin interface. If admin interface, did you get the screen after pressing enable offering to activate the feature?

I would start by checking the log for when you activate the module. It may provide you access to an error message that the orchard UI is hiding.

Comment: I would also check that the module actually builds. A version incompatibility is likely here.